# Firestore data won't load until I change the code in React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I’m starting a new application that will serve as the basis for a real app

It works fine, but Firestore data won't load until I change the code in React

```
// I have one collection with subcollections,
// first collection is oses (operating systems) and the others are:
// The real Operating systems, that are children of the main ones
// In this case, Windows and macOS

export default function App() {
   const [categories, setCategories] = useState({});
   const [startProcessDone, setstartProcessDone] = useState(false);
   const [firstPhaseDone, setFirstPhaseDone] = useState(false);
   const [secondPhaseDone, setSecondPhaseDone] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      setCategories({});
      setstartProcessDone(true);
   }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("in useEffect 1");
      //Here, I read the main ones, which are, in this case
      // Windows and macOS
      const readDocs = async (collectionRef) => {
         const result = {};
         try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocsFromServer(collectionRef);
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
               result[doc.id] = { ...doc.data() };
            });
            setCategories(result);
         } catch (error) {
            console.log("error::: ", error);
         }
      };
      const collectionRef = collection(db, "oses");
      readDocs(collectionRef);
      setFirstPhaseDone(true);
   }, [startProcessDone]);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("in useEffect 2");

      const readDocs = async (prop, collectionRef) => {
         let newOperatingSystems = [];
         let newOperatingSystemObj = {};
         try {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocsFromServer(collectionRef);
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
               newOperatingSystemObj = { ...doc.data() };
               newOperatingSystems[newOperatingSystemObj.name] =
                  newOperatingSystemObj;
            });
            let newCategories = { ...categories };
            newCategories[prop].items = newOperatingSystems;
            setCategories(newCategories);
         } catch (error) {
            console.log("error:: ", error);
         }
      };

      for (var prop in categories) {
         // And for each of the main ones, we have their children, which are, in this case
         // for Windows: Windows XP and Windows Vista
         // for macOS: Big Sur
         //These subcollections are children of the main ones
         const collectionRef = collection(db, `oses/${prop}/children`);
         readDocs(prop, collectionRef);
      }
      setSecondPhaseDone(true);
   }, [firstPhaseDone]);

   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("in useEffect 3.");
      // The result is:
      console.log("categories:: ", categories);
   }, [secondPhaseDone]);

   return (
      <div>
         <h1>Operating Systems</h1>
      </div>
   );
}
```

The result is

[image]

When I change some code, this is what it shows:

[image]

The data is ok

But if I just restart it using [image]

It won't load any data:

[image]

What could I be missing here

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing it a little deeper, I think that it has to do with some kind of cache of FireStore

I tried with another simpler code, and things were the same for the console.logs but the software works fine, even though the console.logs were wrong

I don't understand, but it works

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try doing this way ?

> useEffect(() => { fetchDocs();  }, [])
>
> const fetchDocs = async() => {    const response =
> db.collection('name');  }

Using asynch inside useEffect is never a good idea. It might cause memory leak.